# How to implement a sorting comparator which cascades the related objects?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, grouping, comparator

Suppose, a contiguous array of following type has to be sorted:

```
struct X
{
  string id, parent_id;
  int value;

  bool operator< (const X& x) const { return value < x.value; }
};
```

With aforementioned `operator<`, it creates following sorted array:

```
{i, p,  v}
----------
{a, "", 1}
{b, "", 2}
{c, "", 3}
{dc, c, 4}
{ea, a, 5}
{fb, b, 6}
```

What is the best way to write the comparator, so that it creates following sorted array:

```
{i, p,  v}
----------
{c, "", 3}  // grouping of 'c'
{dc, c, 4}
{a, "", 1}  // grouping of 'a'
{ea, a, 5}
{b, "", 2}  // grouping of 'b'
{fb, b, 6}
```

As you may see, the array is specially sorted where the `parent_id` creates a grouping & then based on the lowest to highest value, the array is arranged. In other words, the latest dependent (those `X`, who have non-empty `parent_id`) objects are the key players. Remaining parents are pulled to them.

**My effort**: The natural way to do this is:

1. Perform sorting with the aforementioned comparator
2. Iterate from the bottom/reverse, i.e. the highest `value`
3. Look for `parent_id` for element `x`; if valid then:

   - search for the `parent_id`, copy & erase that element
   - insert just above `x`
4. Recursively execute step 3 until `parent_id` not found

**Question**: Can this be achieved in any easier way?

**Note**: This problem is not specific to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic here is to add an extra `int` in the `struct X`. Yes, the memory will increase by 4-8 bytes for every object, but it's fine for my requirement.

```
struct X
{
  string id, parent_id;
  int value, value_group = 0;
  //         ^^^^^^^^^^^ new indicator to be used while sorting
  bool operator< (const X& x) const 
  { return (value_group == x.value_group)? value < x.value : value_group < x.value_group; }

  void print () const { cout << "{" << id << ", " << parent_id << ", " << value << ", " << value_group << "}\n"; }
};
```

The other thing is that, the `vector` is updated chronologically & not at once with `{}` (Sorry: This important part I missed to mention in the Qn). So whenever a new element is added, it will pull down its parent near to itself. That logic is mentioned below in form of a class, which contains the collection (`vector, array, list` etc.) & adds the objects:

```
struct MyClass
{
  vector<X> vx;

  void Add (X&& x)
  {
    auto end = vx.end(), it = std::prev(end);
    bool isStandAlone = true;
    for(auto parent_id = x.parent_id;
        not parent_id.empty();
        parent_id = it->parent_id)
      for(auto itPrev = it - 1;
          parent_id != it->id or (isStandAlone = false);
          it = itPrev--)
        if(itPrev == vx.begin())
        {
          it->parent_id.clear();     
          break;
        }

    if(isStandAlone)
      x.parent_id.clear();
    else
    {
      auto begin = it;
      do { it->value_group = x.value; }
      while(++it != end and not it->parent_id.empty());

      decltype(vx) temp(std::make_move_iterator(begin), std::make_move_iterator(it));
      vx.erase(begin, it);
      vx.insert(vx.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
    }
    x.value_group = x.value;
    vx.push_back(std::move(x));
  }
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/4n3dhR).

Answer (score 0):

Your current comparator probably looks like this:

```
int cmp = a.string_id.compare(b.string_id);
if(cmp == 0) {
   cmp = a.parent_id.compare(b.parent_id);
   if(cmp == 0) {
      cmp = a.value - b.value;
   }
}
return cmp < 0;
```

You can achieve your desired sorting by using a slightly different comparator:

```
auto a_effective_parent_id = a.parent_id.empty() ? a.string_id : a.parent_id;
auto b_effective_parent_id = b.parent_id.empty() ? b.string_id : b.parent_id;

// compare first by 'effective' parent id
int cmp = a_effective_parent_id.compare(b_effective_parent_id);
if(cmp == 0) {
   // here we order items with empty parent_id before children
   cmp = a.parend_id.compare(b.parent_id);
   if(cmp == 0) {
     // then compare by 'string_id'
     cmp = a.string_id.compare(b.string_id);
     if(cmp == 0) {
        // and eventually compare by 'value'
        cmp = a.value - b.value;
     }
   } 
}
return cmp < 0;
```

This means that we sort first by `parent_id` and in the case the `parent_id` is empty we do as if the `string_id` was the `parent_id` (what I call an `effective_parent_id`, similar in concept to the effective user id in unix :) ).

In case you cannot modify the class comparator method, you can implement a specific comparator (in a lambda or functor for instance) and use it with `std::sort`.

**Some references:**

- [basic_string::compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)
- [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), with an example of sorting using a lambda and a functor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would have been more helpful, if it was mentioned in form of a working example. Also, I couldn't get the comparison between `string`s. Nevertheless, I have found a solution and have updated in an answer.